# Session variable and Dynamic Pagination in php

Tags: php, html, sql, pagination

```
<form action='movies.php' method='POST'>
    Language: <select  name="language"> 
   <option selected>hindi</option>
   <?php
   require("config.php");
   $result="SELECT language FROM movies";
    $q = mysqli_query($conn,$result) or die(mysql_error());

     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
            $s1=$row["language"];

                echo "<option>
                    $s1
                </option>";

            }
          echo "<br>"      



           ?>
            </select>
            <br /> <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>


<?php

$lang=@$_POST['language'];
$_SESSION["lang1"]=$lang;



/*
if($lang){
$sql = "SELECT name,language FROM movies WHERE language='$lang'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<div class="query"> <img src="images\tiles\bb.jpg"> ';

        echo "<h3> " . $row["name"]."</h3>". "<br>";
        echo "</div>";

    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
}
*/

$page=@$_GET['page'];

if($page==""|| $page=="1")
{
    $page1=0;

}
else{
    $page1=($page*3)-3;

}

$sql = "SELECT name,language FROM movies WHERE language='". $_SESSION['lang1']."' limit $page1,3 ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$a= mysqli_num_rows($result);
while ($list=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

       echo $list['name'] . " :  " . $list['language'] . "<br />";

}

$sql = "SELECT name,language FROM movies WHERE language='$lang'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$a= mysqli_num_rows($result);

$numrows=$a;
$rowsperpage=3;
$totalpages= ceil($numrows/$rowsperpage);

echo "</br>";
for($b=1;$b<=$totalpages;$b++)
{
    ?><a href="movies.php?page=<?php echo $b; ?> "><?php echo $b." ";?> </a> <?php

}   

?>
```

I get proper output on movies.php which is the first 3 rows from database,but when i click on the dynamically created pagination link like movies.php?page=2 then there is no output on this page.This code works fine if i manually set the 
$_SESSION["lang1"]="English"; then i get proper output but when i take input from the form it doesnt work.

Comment: you  have use `session_start()` for using `$_SESSION`

Comment: I have used it at the beginning

Comment: try to `echo $lang` because you are saying  when you set the value of session variable than this code is working properly .

Comment: on first page i get the output , the name of language but nothing on second page

Comment: the variable resets when i load the next page

Comment: @SrikaranShenviSursure Did you get the solution? I am also facing the same error. Need help.

Comment: I did complete it using some method but i have not used php for a long time. This is the file  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=90618213052460224063. And the site is https://srikaransursure.000webhostapp.com